# How to pass a constant or literal data via an attribute while instantiating dart web component?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Definition:

```html
<element name="x-card" constructor="Card" extends="div">
  <template>
    <div>{{titleText}}</div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

    class Card extends WebComponent {
      String titleText = '';
    }
  </script>
</element>
```

Instantiation:

```html
<x-card data-value="titleText:something"></x-card>
```

or

```html
<x-card titleText="something"></x-card>
```

Nothing is working.
Here `something` is not a variable. Its a string literal. How do i go about passing it?
Also what if i want to instantiate array of `x-cards`? Say i have a dart array named `cardTitleArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@financeCoding, data-value is deprecated. They say use `attribute=value` instead of `data-value="attribute:value"`.

Never mind, my problem is solved. The following works.

```html
<x-card title-text="{{'Aint it supercool'}}"></x-card>
```

Comment: Use comment on the financeCoding answer instead.

Comment: There is an open feature request to make literal attributes work. https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/240

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code that does make reference to 'data-value'

http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/#component-instantiation

https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/master/example/explainer/countcomponent.html

It does not seem like the actual code uses it. Could you use the other way or now or post the code online? Maybe a space is needed after ':' ?